# Changing Padding of TextView in a ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview with an arrayadapter that holds these views

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

 <CheckedTextView        
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_item"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall" >
 </CheckedTextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to add X padding to the left of the textview when activated and remove that padding when not selected. The padding will not update. How do I manage this?

Comment: You can change it in your Adapter

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no setOnActivatedListener and setOnClickListener absorbs the click event so that it does not activate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have your `CheckedTextView` within a `ListView` you can set an `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` on the `ListView` using the `setOnItemSelectedListener (AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener listener)` method and override the `onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)` method.

Inside that `onItemClick()` method, you check to see which one was the view that was clicked (by comparing the `position` variable that shows the position of the view that was clicked, with your `CheckedTextView`'s actual position to see if they match). Then if your user has indeed click in your `CheckedTextView` you check to see if the `CheckedTextView.isChecked ()` is true. If it is true, change the padding programmatically, else let it be.

Comment: I had to update the whole list during the onItemClick. For some reason it would not work anywhere else. Thanks.